# Опять не получается перечислить массив помогите как правильно?

Tags: php, массивы

вот собствено и сам виновник

```
  array(10) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#110 (7) { 
            ["id"]=> string(5) "27741" 
            ["type"]=> string(8) "KPPeople" 
            ["nameRU"]=> string(30) "Джей Джей Абрамс" 
            ["nameEN"]=> string(11) "J.J. Abrams" 
            ["posterURL"]=> string(29) "actor_iphone/iphone_27741.jpg" 
            ["professionText"]=> string(18) "Режиссеры" 
            ["professionKey"]=> string(8) "director" }
    } 
    [1]=> array(127) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#108 (8) { 
            ["id"]=> string(7) "2196854" 
            ["type"]=> string(8) "KPPeople" 
            ["nameRU"]=> string(21) "Джон Бойега" 
            ["nameEN"]=> string(11) "John Boyega" 
            ["description"]=> string(4) "Finn" 
            ["posterURL"]=> string(31) "actor_iphone/iphone_2196854.jpg" 
            ["professionText"]=> string(12) "Актеры" 
            ["professionKey"]=> string(5) "actor" } 
        [1]=> object(stdClass)#111 (8) { 
            ["id"]=> string(7) "3016071" 
            ["type"]=> string(8) "KPPeople" 
            ["nameRU"]=> string(21) "Дэйзи Ридли" 
            ["nameEN"]=> string(12) "Daisy Ridley" 
            ["description"]=> string(3) "Rey" 
            ["posterURL"]=> string(31) "actor_iphone/iphone_3016071.jpg" ["professionText"]=> string(12) "Актеры" 
            ["professionKey"]=> string(5) "actor" }...
    } 
    [2]=> array(14) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#237 (7) { 
            ["id"]=> string(5) "27741" 
            ["type"]=> string(8) "KPPeople" 
            ["nameRU"]=> string(30) "Джей Джей Абрамс" 
            ["nameEN"]=> string(11) "J.J. Abrams" 
            ...} 
    [3]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#251 (7) {
            ["id"]=> string(7) "2469864" 
            ["type"]=> string(8) "KPPeople" 
            ["nameRU"]=> string(33) "Георгий Даниелянц" 
            ["nameEN"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["posterURL"]=> string(31) "actor_iphone/iphone_2469864.jpg" ["professionText"]=> string(33) "Режиссеры дубляжа" 
            ["professionKey"]=> string(14) "voice_director" 
        } 
    }...
```

получить мне надо id,nameRU,posterURL и professionKey причем количество массивов первого уровня и второго как видите может быть от 0 до бесконечности

Comment: а чем вложенный foreach в foreach не устраивает? У вас в конце же объект, так что во втором цикле нужно обращаться как с объектом соответственно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вложенный цикл тут, по-моему, вполне уместен:

```
$data = array(/* ... */); // ваш исходный массив
for( $i=0; $i<count( $data); $i++) {
    $inner = $data[ $i];
    if( !is_array( $inner) || count( $inner)===0) continue;
    for( $j=0; $j<count( $inner); $j++) {
        $item = $inner[ $j];
        printf(
            '<li>%d "%s"<br><img src="%s" alt=""><br>(%s)</li>',
            $item->id,
            $item->nameRU,
            $item->posterURL,
            $item->professionKey
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = array(....);
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($source, function ($item, $key) use (&$result)
{
    if(isset($item['id']){
        $result[]=array(
          'id'=>$item['id'],
          'nameRU'=>$item['nameRU'],
          'posterURL'=>$item['posterURL'],
          'professionKey'=>$item['professionKey']
        );
    }
});
```